How to ensure rabbitmq messages of same topic are published over same channel in a multichannel environment
I am using spring amqp multi thread environment and have multiple channels on one mq connection shared between these threads. Messages with various topics are published on these channels. Need to maintain ordering of messages having same topic and to achieve this I need to publish them to same channel each time. How can I achieve this? Does spring provide some provision to choose a fixed channel among available list of channels?

You probably need to look into a dedicated CachingConnectionFactory for your RabbitTemplate with size 1 for the pool of channels.
Another candidate is a ThreadChannelConnectionFactory, but you need to ensure that all your producers send messages to the same thread where such a RabbitTemplate instance would reuse the mentioned channel attached to that thread.
See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/connections.html

Okay Thanks! But does ThreadChannelConnectionFactory use seperate channel for each thread? I have huge number of threads so can't create that many channels. Can these threads share a fixed number of channels?
So there are n channels created and any new thread will use one of these channels and it will use this same channel each time. So channel n1 can be used by multiple threads t1, t2, t3 but t1 will always use n1.
Can this be achieved? I tried checking the documentation but that didn't help much.

Then I think you need to experiment with a CachingConnectionFactory and sessionCacheSize = 1, and channelCheckoutTimeout > 0. See its JavaDocs for more info.
